# How can I draw custom shapes on Graphics layer?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, flex, arcgis-flex-viewer

Hello everyone I need help. Any clue, guidance or help that would be appreciated, please bear with me as I am still struggling with Flex 4.

1. What is the simplest way to draw custom shapes using < s : path> on graphic layer. I had data for the  already created.
2. How can I pass my own styles in SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_CIRCLE, 22, 0x009933) in place of STYLE_CIRCLE? 
   I want to create my own styles so that I can explicitly use them there like STYLE_RECT. 
   Can I pass my path data in any symbol like fillsymbol, linesymbol or markersymbol so that they draw the shape?
3. How can I extend these symbol classes so that I can use member functions and properties of these symbols + my MXML code?

I am using SFV 2.4.
Thanks